# The Akimichi Clan Symbol

Tags: naruto

The symbol for the Akimichi clan is:

[image]

Does it mean anything in Japanese? If so, what is it?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct symbol... The one on wiki is difference http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Akimichi_Clan Manga not handy enough to check

Comment: @Arcane you actually see that symbol in the [first image](https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/0/0e/Akimichi_clan.png/revision/latest?cb=20150822041719) on that page and the wikia page doesn't seem to explain why it's different

Comment: @Memor-X Not sure. The symbol on the wikia looks like it is alluding to the hidden ability of Akimichi clan to burn Fat to create chakra wings, cos it looks like a butterfly to me :P

Comment: It's mentioned on the Wikia: "*As a tribute, members of the clan wear the kanji for "food" (食, shoku) on the their clothing*"

Comment: @AkiTanaka Nice spot! For reference... http://thejapanesepage.com/kanji/%E9%A3%9F

Comment: Lol im not japanese and even i recognize it means food. Seems like the jap langauge is a ripoff of the chinese language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol comes from the [**食** kanji](http://www.kanji-a-day.com/dictionary/kanji-detail.php?id=1031). You can prononces it "uka" and it means food or to eat. You can also prononce it "uke", "ke", "shoku" or "shi", but it gives the kanji almost the same meaning of food or meal.

Hope that helped.

Comment: That really relates to what the akimichi are good at: eating :)